# Copy sections from one form to another form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am using Scripts to update multiple Google Forms that share the same first two pages/sections, but have an entirely different third page/section.

For instance,

Form 1: Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 3 > Submit

Form 2: Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 4 > Submit

Form 3: Page 1 > Page 2 > Page 5 > Submit

I KNOW I can put a question on page 2 that directs to either 3, 4, or 5 depending on the answer to that question. However, **the customer has requested three distinct forms with different URLs, ruling out that possibility.**

Current, I update all three forms separately:

1. Remove everything from Form 1, then rebuild it from scratch.

2. Remove everything from Form 2, then rebuild it from scratch.

3. Remove everything from Form 3, then rebuild it from scratch.

My question is: **is there any way to generate pages 1 and 2, then "copy" them to all three forms?**

1. Rebuild pages 1 and 2 (say on a dummy form).

2. Copy pages 1 and 2 to Form 1. Rebuild page 3.

3. Copy pages 1 and 2 to Form 2. Rebuild Page 4.

4. Copy pages 1 and 2 to Form 3. Rebuild Page 5.

I also know I can make one form with pages 1 and 2, then make a copy of that form three times and work with the copies. However, **the customer wants the URLs to remain the same through form updates.** I cannot work with copies because copying a form generates a new URL for it. I have to update the already existing forms.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are no such methods available to the Form service.

Comment: The question is too broad as it emcompases several "subquestions". Please limit the post to only one question.

Comment: @Rubén really I only see the one question: **Is there any way to generate items on one `Form` and copy/move them to another `Form`?** The rest is more ideas about using that necessary functionality

Comment: @codepants Why do you need to remove everything from all the forms? Why not simply keep pages 1 and 2 for all three forms and then update the sections unique to a given form as needed?

Comment: The approach taken by OP in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288629/copying-images-between-google-form-quizzes may be useful. Note that the method will need to be done for each utilized class of `Item`.

Comment: @Rubén there is a lot of stipulation but only one question: is it possible to programmatically copy form sections from one form to another?

Comment: @DimuDesigns I don't need to remove everything, but pages 1 and 2 contain options/items that are frequently updated. If I make major changes to pages 1 and 2 on form 1, it would be faster to just copy those updated pages to forms 2 and 3 than make the same changes again on those forms.

Answer (score 1):

On this question I see several underlying issues:

1. Form structure

   - FormApp manage questions, "pages" and "sections" by using several kinds of items that could be handled by using the [Interface Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item) for all of them. There aren't containers or parent-child relationship between these items.
2. Copy items

   - FormApp doesn't include a copy method for items but it's possible to set the same property object to several items.
3. Keep the same URL

   - Google Forms URLs are unique and can't be reused. There are reports of forms that become unusable so it's better to be prepared in case that his happens (don't make promises that the form URL will not ever change). One way is to use a parameter to handle form ids/URLs instead of hardcoding them.